# "action" attribute is not working in "Angular" template

Tags: angular, forms, form-data, angular-template

**Requirement:**

I need to post a *form data* using `action` attribute from a contact form in `Angular`.

**Problem:**

The solution is working if we create a static file with this form. but attribute `action` doesn't seems to be working when using inside an `angular` template. It seems NO action is being performed when clicking.

**My form:**

```
<form 
    id="gform" 
    action="https://script.google.com/sampleUrl" 
    method="POST" 
    [formGroup]="form" 
    fxLayout="column" 
    fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" name="Name" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid">Please enter a Name</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="e-mail" formControlName="email" name="Email" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('email').invalid">Please enter a valid e-mail</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Number" formControlName="number" name="Phone" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('number').invalid">Please enter phone number</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" >Submit</button> -->
</form>
```

**Version info:**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.2
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      6.2.2
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.18
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.8.2
@schematics/update                0.8.2
rxjs                              6.3.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

**Note:** I am trying to use google spreadsheet api, to write into a google doc. Facing CORS issue when using a method call,

Comment: ohh .. Whats might be the alternative solution, Option via a method doesn't seems to be solution because of CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to get data you use (submit)

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit(form)">...</form>
```

If your .ts

```
submit(form)
{
   if (form.valid)
     this.httpClient.post("https://script.google.com/sampleUrl",form.value)
         .subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
}
```

If you want to redirect to a new page, use a simple form but not forget write **ngNoForm**, https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm else Angular convert your form in a form of angular

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i am getting ''Access-Control-Allow-Origin'' error when using this way, hence not able to use this option. any work around to avoid this ?